# How to draw vertical gradient in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext, gradient

I am trying to draw a vertical gradient at the bottom of an iTextSharp pdf document:

```
PdfShading shading 
    = PdfShading.SimpleAxial(pdfWriter, 0, document.PageSize.Height, 
                             document.PageSize.Width, 0, BaseColor.WHITE, BaseColor.GREEN);
PdfShadingPattern pattern = new PdfShadingPattern(shading);
pdfContentByte.SetShadingFill(pattern);
pdfContentByte.Rectangle(0, 0, document.PageSize.Width, 70);
pdfContentByte.Fill();
```

This creates a gradient at the exact position I want it to be created, but the gradient is horizontal from left (white) to right (green).

**I want the gradient to be vertical from top (white) to bottom (green).**

Modifying the coordinates like some one did here ([Does iTextsharp support multi color diagonal gradients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282164/does-itextsharp-support-multi-color-diagonal-gradients)) did not solve the problem. I also tried to rotate the document but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong coordinates. In Java, you'd need something like this:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(150, 300);
    Document document = new Document(pageSize);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfShading shading = PdfShading.simpleAxial(writer,
            0, pageSize.getHeight(),
            0, 0,
            BaseColor.WHITE, BaseColor.GREEN);
    PdfShadingPattern pattern = new PdfShadingPattern(shading);
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    canvas.setShadingFill(pattern);
    canvas.rectangle(0, 0, pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight());
    canvas.fill();
    document.close();
}
```

See [GradientTopToBottom](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/graphics/pattern-colors#1575-gradienttoptobottom.java) for the full sample code.

Do you see the difference?

- You go from the left-top corner (`0, document.PageSize.Height`) to the right-bottom corner (`document.PageSize.Width, 0`). That's a diagonal.
- You want to go from the top (`0, document.PageSize.Height`) to the bottom (`0, 0`) which leads to the following result: [gradient_top_to_bottom.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/graphics/cmp_gradient_top_to_bottom.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much. Needed to make slight changes in not using the full height... but anyway that's it.