# iTextSharp C# - PdfPTable Gradient Color - How to?

Tags: c#, itext

I saw this tutorial [Example gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433510/how-to-draw-vertical-gradient-in-itextsharp) for full page gradient but I only need it for PdfPTable that must be colored with a gradient that start from:

```
BaseColor gradientStart = new BaseColor(137, 24, 28);
BaseColor gradientEnd = new BaseColor(169, 31, 42);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manipulate table backgrounds, you can use table events. E.g. for your task:

```
public class GradientTableBackground : IPdfPTableEvent
{
    public GradientTableBackground(PdfWriter writer)
    {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public void TableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] widths, float[] heights, int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        BaseColor gradientStart = ...;
        BaseColor gradientEnd = ...);

        float[] topWidths = widths[0];
        PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(topWidths[0], heights[heights.Length - 1], topWidths[topWidths.Length - 1], heights[0]);

        PdfShading shading = PdfShading.SimpleAxial(writer, rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, gradientStart, gradientEnd);
        PdfShadingPattern pattern = new PdfShadingPattern(shading);
        cb.SetShadingFill(pattern);
        cb.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
        cb.Fill();
    }

    PdfWriter writer;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
table = new PdfPTable(columns);
table.TableEvent = new GradientTableBackground(writer);
...
document.Add(table);
```

Using red and green for `gradientStart` and `gradientEnd` the result looks like this:

[image: table with red-green gradient]

Using your colors, though, one hardly sees the gradient:

[image: table with gradient with OP's colors]

Comment: Thanks very much for your best help!!! I was going crazy but you teached me a new useful thing! Thanks!

Comment: About -1 for my topic make me thinking (who made it) that he was a "pirla"

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe that person would have liked seeing more code from your attempts. According to that criterion, though, one can downvote half the questions here...